# How to group numeric values by hours?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
df =

MONTH DAY HOUR DURATION
1     1   7    20 
1     1   7    21 
1     2   7    20
1     2   8    22
2     1   7    19
2     1   8    25
2     1   8    29
2     2   8    27
```

I want to get the mean `DURATION` grouped by `HOUR` and averaged over `MONTH` and `DAY`. In other words, I want to know what is the average `DURATION` per `HOUR`.

This is my current code. If I delete `'MONTH','DAY'` from `df.groupby(['MONTH','DAY','HOUR','DURATION'])`, then I get higher values of `DURATION`, which are not correct. Therefore I decided to keep `'MONTH','DAY'`.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['MONTH','DAY','HOUR','DURATION']).size() \
    .groupby(level=['HOUR','DURATION']).mean().reset_index()
grouped
```

However, anyway, it gives me incorrect output. This is an example for some random data (it can be seen that the hour `8` is repeated many times, also the column `0` appears).

```
    HOUR    DURATION    0
0   7   122.0   1.0
1   8   77.0    1.0
2   8   82.0    1.0
3   8   83.0    1.0
```

Comment: `df.groupby("HOUR").DURATION.mean()`?

Comment: @Psidom: What if I need to add more variables besides `DURATION`? Can I do `df.groupby("HOUR").["DURATION_1","DURATION_2"].mean()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
df.groupby("HOUR").agg({'DURATION_1' : 'mean', 'DURATION_2' : 'mean'})
```

Comment: @JonClemens my little dino was more funny